# IF statement with multiple worksheets in Excel

Tags: excel, if-statement

I have a worksheet called Start at the beginning and a worksheet called End at the end of the sheets.

On my sheet in the middle, I want a cell to add up all of the I7 values from Start to End and if it is greater than 0 to display 0. If not, I want it to display the sum of all of the I7 values.

When I use this formula:

```
=IF(Start!I7:End!I7>0, 0, Start!I7:End!I7)
```

I get the error `#value!`

This formula works if I do `=IF(Start!I7-End!I7>0, 0, Start!I7-End!I7)` with the subtraction.

Comment: =IF(MIN(START:END!I7)>0, 0, MIN(START:END!I7))

This is my latest formula. Doesn't give me the right answer. Telling me 0.

I have 3 sheets where I7 is: 643, 792, 55. The answer should be -204 (643-792-55). The cells are empty in START and END sheets.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(Start!I7+End!I7>0, 0, Start!I7+End!I7)
```

or are you asking to sum all pages between and including Start and End?  You're subtraction equation only references those two pages...

Comment: I want it to do all the sheets in-between. I would actually like it to subtract all of the tabs, not add but I don't know anyway to do the range of tabs besides add them like I originally did.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the sum function, but the syntax for summing the same cell across multiple sheets is a little different than what you have.

```
=IF(SUM(Start:End!I7) > 0, 0, SUM(Start:End!I7))
```

Refer to the sheet range, then the cell.

After your other question, I think the way to subtract all the subsequent `I7` cells from the first one would be to just sum everything after it the same way we're doing here and subtract that from the initial value.

```
=IF(Start!I7 - SUM(Sheet2:End!I7) > 0, 0, Start!I7 - SUM(Sheet2:End!I7))
```

(I used Sheet2 as a placeholder. You would use the name of whatever sheet comes after `Start`.)

I think that it could be written more simply, though, using `MIN`.

```
=MIN(Start!I7 - SUM(Sheet2:End!I7), 0)
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks! Is it possible to subtract the range instead of add them? Otherwise I'll just have to make the numbers negative on the sheets. Thanks.

Comment: Hm, do you mean begin with the value in `Start!I7` and subtract all the other `I7` values from that?

Comment: Yes that is what I would like. Thanks